# Simple scapy script not sending packet

Tags: python, scapy

I have the most simple scapy script possible but It is not working. Please help:

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)
scan("192.169.11.117")
```

When it runs I get this:

```
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.

Received 0 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

How can I fix this and actually get answers?

Comment: Might be a firewall problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem #1

You are likely using the wrong subnet. Private subnets ([RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)) are

- 10.0.0.0/8
- 172.16.0.0/12
- 192.168.0.0/16

You probably meant to do this, which is a private IP address

```
scan("192.168.11.117")
```

and not this

```
scan("192.169.11.117")
```

which is a public IP address. It's also possible that you own this public subnet, in which case this is not relevant.

#### Problem #2

The remote host may not be responding because it doesn't exist at that address. Make sure to double check that the target whose IP you are using in `arping` is online and accessible.

You can check arp mappings on *nix and windows by using `arp -a` on your command line

```
$ arp -a

? (192.168.1.111) at 0:1b:78:20:ee:40 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.112) at a4:77:33:88:92:62 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.117) at 6c:33:a9:42:6a:18 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
...
```

for the target IP to make sure that a scapy `arping` *should* resolve.

---

If you are trying to do an ARP scan, then you should look at Cukic0'ds answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use it.

Have a look at the doc:
https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#arp-ping

```
arping("192.169.11.*")
```

You should look up what an ARP scan is. You don't just send a packet to a single IP, but to a range (using a submask).